# how to get a class value from an iframe parent page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, iframe, parent

I have two applications one is already built and the other one is my own I can't do any modification in the first one and it uses iframes and in that frame I can put my application but I will need the name of the connected users which the only option is to get it from the source code using javascript the problem is that user name inside a css class not id 
if you have any ideas how can I get it please help thanks to you all

```
            <div class="Entete_User">
            <div class="Entete_UserName">USER NAME <br> USER CITY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <iframe id="myiframe" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="allowTransparency" src="MYPAGE.aspx"></iframe>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: are the pages in the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content of the element in the parent window from inside the iFrame :

```
window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName('Entete_UserName')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this but make sure Iframe and your `origin` page in same domain as `iframe` does not support `cross domain`

JavaScript

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('parentElement')[0].innerHTML;;
```

Jquery

```
 $('#parentElement', window.parent.document);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is for outside the iframe trying to see whats inside..

document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById()

but you have to be on the same domain